# Can a property change without its setter getting called?

Tags: c#

I have a simple property within a Model class with a getter and setter

```
private bool _isThresholdBreached;
public bool IsThresholdBreached
{
  get
  {
      return _isThresholdBreached;
  }
  set
  {
      if(_isThresholdBreached == value)
         return;
      _isThresholdBreached = value;
      OnThresholdBreached?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs()); 
  }    
}
```

Strangely enough the property's value is getting changed without the setter getter hit. I have put a breakpoint both within the getter and setter and I see that when the getter is called on successive occasions the value has changed but the setter breakpoint never hit. How is this even possible ? Any pointers please.

EDIT : I have verified and can confirm that the backing field is not modified anywhere else in the class except in the setter

Comment: "How is this even possible?" -> What if the backing field is changed?

Comment: if you directly access the `_isThresholdBreached` field within the class then it is possible since it is set to private.

Comment: I would suggest reading the following [C# MSDN Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Comment: Temporary convert your field into property (without changing name) and put breakpoint in setter. That way you will finally find out what sets it (or exception if someone sets it via reflection).

Answer (score 5):

Your property has a backing field. 
Any code calling the field directly would update that value without calling the setter (this could be both direct or via reflection).

I would start with `Find usages` of the `_isThresholdBreached` followed by full text search in the solution.

Comment: thanks. I have done both, but there is nothing. I was really stumped that's why came to stackoverflow looking for any other pointers.

Comment: @C.Dhruv Can you step through all threads executing in your app? e.g. place a breakpoint at each of the entries there and just debug the code.